# What type of DC power connector do I need?

Tags: display

I have the LG Flatron IPS224V-PN monitor and I need a power connector for it.
The socket can be seen on the back of the monitor:
[image]

I want to know what is the name of this type of power connector.

Comment: Are you looking just for the jack component, or for a complete replacement DC power supply? I have a feeling that this question may get closed as an electronics repair question, as opposed to an electronics design question.

Comment: i want the male jack compenent that power adapter has.

Comment: I am tagging this question to be closed as this question is Off topic

Comment: @annacarolina as far as I know the identification of components is on topic - I added the identification tag to it, the rest of my edit might not have been the best.

Comment: Identifying a jack, even on consumer products IS ON TOPIC!

Comment: It's a barrel connector with an inner pin. Not knowing the dimensions, It may be the EIAJ-05 (6.50 Outer Dimension,4.30 Inner, 1.40 center pin in mm). Radioshack Size T. Or maybe R or U. They have a couple with inner pins.

Comment: Migrated why ffs...

Answer (score 3):

That is a coaxial power connector, generally dimensionally specified by two numbers, an inner pin diameter (in mm) and an outer barrel diameter (in mm). Officially, they are described by **IEC 60130-10**, but they are generally referred to as **DC barrel jacks**. You can read more about them at [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coaxial_power_connector).

In order to find the correct part for your monitor, just measure the barrel diameter and pin diameter on the female socket on the monitor, and look for a male counterpart. The Wikipedia page I linked shows the commonly available sizes, so you will need to match your measurements to the nearest standard dimension.

Comment: No, a barrel connector is different. The one pictured in the question has a double cylinder shape, so likely the cable connector has both a cylinder barrel and a pin on that side. Barrel connectors the pin is on the pcb side.

Comment: Sorry, my bad - good spot @Passerby. This is definitely not the same as a barrel jack, but it is similar. I am going to look at this later and modify, unless someone beats me to it with a better answer.

Comment: Apparently they are under the same wiki page. Under Radioshack U or R maybe?

Answer (score 0):

For the record, based on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/198131/identifing-monitor-dc-power-connector this is most likely an EIAJ-05 as @cde suggested.